# jquery show/hide all children of given element

Tags: jquery, html

In this html:

```css
    $('#endre_dinmeny').click(function() {
        $('.form-validate').children('.label-visible').hide();
        $('.form-validate').children('.edit-visible').show();
    });
```

```html
<span id="endre_dinmeny" class="col-md-6 bestill-edit2">Endre</span>
<div class="form-validate">
  <div class="row">
    <label class="col-md-4">
      Leveringsfrekvens
    </label>
    <div class="label-visible">
      view
    </div>
    <div class="edit-visible">
      edit
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing so wrong that it doesn't do absolutetly nothing? I've been up almost 48h straigh so please, be gentle if you spot a noob error, but I'm tired of banging my head with this..

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
 $('.form-validate').find('.label-visible').hide();
 $('.form-validate').find('.edit-visible').show();
```

`find('.label-visible')` will not work because `.label-visible` is not a direct child.

`children()` will only search **direct** descendants. Find will search direct **and** nested descendants.

Finally, if you have multiple `.form-validate` elements, you should narrow your context by using `$(this)`

```
$(this).find('.form-validate .label-visible').hide();
$(this).find('.form-validate .edit-visible').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

To toggle the children of given element, you have to use `find`. But the most important thing is that you have to use it with the current element, `$(this)`

```
  $('#endre_dinmeny').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.form-validate .label-visible').hide();
    $(this).find('.form-validate .edit-visible').show();
  });
```

Comment: Hi Mario, that doesn't seem to do it.. I'm guessing that probably because I have a lot more divs between the .form-validate and the divs with .label-visible and .edit-visible. I need to traverse all children of form-validate and find the ones with those names and show/hide them..

Comment: Hey Zed, the selector '.form-validate .label-visible' finds all of your label-visible inside form-validate, it's not a problem the tags between form and label. I really do not understand why is not working :(

Comment: @Zed_Blade, can you reproduce it in a fiddle?